# External Authentication Services ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, azure

I am using visual studio 2013 and i created a single page Application Project.

Then in App_start folder startup_Auth.cs file i Add facebook appId and app secret.

Then I hosted this project to azure website. And Of course I added this site name to facebook app setting as site url.

I published site, on which I tried to login with facebook.
After the user is logged in it returns to application and then it following error in browser.

```
<Error>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
</Error>
```

What did I do wrong. Basically I just followed [this](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/external-authentication-services) link. To achieve the requirement

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: please give description of the error . i think the app is not redirected to correct address or the user only allowed to login if the app is in sandbox mode